# Tensorflow: Tensor.set_shape() ValueError: 'image' must be fully defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to use `tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad` to crop a part of the input image. But there comes an error: `ValueError: 'image' must be fully defined`. And I checked the [Why do I get ValueError('\'image\' must be fully defined.') when transforming image in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746777/why-do-i-get-valueerror-image-must-be-fully-defined-when-transforming-im) I added `Tensor.set_shape()` but it also cannot work.
I list my code and error as follow:

```
example = tf.image.decode_png(file_contents, channels=3)
example.set_shape = ([256,256,3])
crop_image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(example, crop_size, crop_size)
```

Error:

```
File "/home/kang/Documents/work_code_PC1/VGG_tensorflow_UCMerced/readUClandUsedImagetxt.py", line 97, in _input_pipeline
    crop_image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, crop_size, crop_size)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops.py", line 534, in resize_image_with_crop_or_pad
    _Check3DImage(image, require_static=True)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops.py", line 221, in _Check3DImage
    raise ValueError('\'image\' must be fully defined.')

ValueError: 'image' must be fully defined.
```

I do not know why the error comes out even I set the certain shape to Image.
But, I test the code like this:

```
example = tf.image.decode_png(file_contents, channels=3)
example = tf.reshape(example, [256,256,3])
crop_image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(example, crop_size, crop_size)
```

It works. I think reshape to the same shape does not change the order of values in Tensor, am I right? Maybe it can be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at the line

```
example.set_shape = ([256,256,3])
```

You're overriding the method `tf.Tensor.set_shape` and setting it to a value.

`set_shape` is a method, thus you have to call it properly:

```
example.set_shape([256,256,3])
```

After that, your code will work.

> I think reshape to the same shape does not change the order of values in Tensor, am I right?

Yes, you're right