# image resize_func error in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am following https://www.kaggle.com/freeman89/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition/create-dataset-with-tensorflow

The problem is about **tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad**

```
resize_func = lambda image: tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, HEIGHT, WIDTH)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-907e45393ea9> in <module>()
----> 1 processed_train_images = decode_image(train_image_file_names, resize_func=resize_func)
      2 processed_test_images = decode_image(test_image_file_names, resize_func=resize_func)

<ipython-input-4-bd49dae09433> in decode_image(image_file_names, resize_func)
     12         image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file)
     13         if resize_func != None:
---> 14             image = resize_func(image)
     15 
     16     with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:

<ipython-input-11-a8bf1ee259c1> in <lambda>(image)
      1 WIDTH=500
      2 HEIGHT=500
----> 3 resize_func = lambda image: tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, HEIGHT, WIDTH)

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops.pyc in resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, target_height, target_width)
    532   """
    533   image = ops.convert_to_tensor(image, name='image')
--> 534   _Check3DImage(image, require_static=True)
    535   original_height, original_width, _ = _ImageDimensions(image)
    536 

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops.pyc in _Check3DImage(image, require_static)
    219     raise ValueError('\'image\' must be three-dimensional.')
    220   if require_static and not image_shape.is_fully_defined():
--> 221     raise ValueError('\'image\' must be fully defined.')
    222   if any(x == 0 for x in image_shape):
    223     raise ValueError('all dims of \'image.shape\' must be > 0: %s' %

ValueError: 'image' must be fully defined.
```

Reference: [Why do I get ValueError('\'image\' must be fully defined.') when transforming image in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746777/why-do-i-get-valueerror-image-must-be-fully-defined-when-transforming-im)

Comment: Do you know what the shape of the image should be? Have you tried setting it with set_shape?

Comment: Are you using queues?

Answer (score -1):

u can use tf.map_fn() to fix this problem